# Pegar Latitude e Longitude a partir de um endereço

Tags: android

Até semana passada esse código que eu havia feita estava dando tudo certo, até que hoje fui testar de novo e me aparece isto:

```
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3660)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17088)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3655)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    ... 11 more
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:178)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2.MainActivity.getLatLng(MainActivity.java:131)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationdistancetimemapv2.MainActivity.goTo(MainActivity.java:149)
05-28 08:22:12.851: E/AndroidRuntime(19605):    ... 14 more
```

O código para de executar no momento que ele faz essa requisição:

```java
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(endereco, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar essa permissão no arquivo de manifesto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> Traduzida [dessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945188/unable-to-parse-response-from-server-geocoder/17945310#17945310) resposta do SOEN.
>   O caso parece ser similar ao seu, e aparentemente essa foi a solução aceita.

Comment: já tem essa permissão

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi, IOException é uma exception, quando você não pode salvar em disco, ou há algum erro ao salvar em disco. No seu caso só acontece em um caso especifico?

Comment: não acontecia, anteriormente tudo rodava perfeito, mas hoje fui testar colocar um endereço para obter a lat e long, e caiu nisso.

Comment: qualquer endereço que eu tente, ele da essa exception

Comment: tanto que agora, repentinamente, voltou a funcionar e não sei o porque

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi. Há a possibilidade que seja um problema na sua rede. Tente testar em outra rede. Ou talvez até mesmo no serviço do Google (pouco provável, já que é estável).

Comment: então, eu levantei esses pontos, e irei fazer um tratamento de erro pro usuário acabar tentando novamente.